# Windows/Linux: Can a malicious program read/write the memory-mapped space of a PCIe peripheral?

Tags: security, device-driver

I apologize in advance for the lack of precision in my phrasing/terminology...I'm not a system programmer by any means...
This is a security-related programming question...at work, I've been asked to assess the "risk" to a PCIe add-in card depending on the integrity of the host operating-system (specifically, Windows Server 2012 x64, and Redhat Enterprise 6/7 x86-64.)

So my question is this: 
We have a PCIe-peripheral (add-in board) that contains several embedded processors that will handle sensitive data. The preferred solution would be to encrypt the data before it enters the PCIe-bus, and decrypt it after it leaves the PCIe-bus...but we can't do this for a variety of reasons (performance, cost, etc.)   Instead, we'll be passing data in cleartext form over the PCIe-bus.

Let's assume an attacker has network access to the machine, but not *physical* access.  If a vendor's PCIe-endpoint device is installed in a server, and the vendor's (signed) driver is up and running with the associated hardware, is it possible for a malicious process/thread to access (read/write) the PCI memory-mapped space(s) of the PCIe-endpoint?

I know there are utilities that allow me to dump (read) the pci config space of all endpoints in a pcie hierarchy...but I have no idea if that extends to reading and writing inside the memory-mapped windows of the installed endpoints (especially if the endpoint is already associated with a device-driver.)

Also, if this is possible, how difficult is it? 
Are we talking a user-space program being able to do this, or does it require the attacker to have root/admin-access to the machine (to run a program of his design, or install a fake/proxy driver.)?

Also, does virtualization make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing device memory requires operating in a lower protection ring than userland software, also known as kernel mode. The only way to access it is going through a driver or the kernel.

Comment: Thanks!  So it sounds like you're saying if the vendor's device driver is already installed and enumerated for the PCIe-peripheral, then no other (malicious) device-driver can hijack and access the peripheral's memory-mapped space...i.e. other programs cannot access the peripheral's memory-mapped device registers?  I'm worried about a PCIe debugging-tool (which would have running on the same PC being able to peek/poke into the peripheral's memory-space.

Comment: Please refer to the following documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554389(v=vs.85).aspx